# Parse a table from stdin

Tags: java, parsing, input, tabular

From stdin input line by line get a table like:

```
3 9 $12  $7  $2
4 $5  1 $4  $21
12  $11 0 0  $17
```

I need to parse it in a such way, so  that I will have two 2d lists:
 1) Just a table of numbers:

```
3 9 12 7 2
4 5 1 4 21
12 11 0 0 17
```

2) table, in which true will mean that there was a dollar sign in front of a number:

```
false false true true true
false true false true true
false true false false true
```

Which is the best way to do this?

I've had the following code:

```
public static List[] parseTable() {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> vals = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Boolean>> truthtable = new ArrayList<>();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String mark = "$";
    try {
        while (true) {
            String[] splitline = reader.readLine().split("\\s+");
            ArrayList<Integer> valsrow = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<Boolean> truthrow = new ArrayList<>();
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitline));
            for (String element: splitline) {
                if (element.startsWith(mark)) {
                    truthrow.add(true);
                }
                else {
                    truthrow.add(false);
                }
                valsrow.add(Integer.parseInt(el.replaceAll(mark, "")));
            }
            vals.add(valsrow); truthtable.add(truthrow);
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        List[] output = new List[2];
        res[0] = truthtable; res[1] = vals;
        return  output;
    }
```

but it does not correctly strip spaces and results in a

```
NumberFormatException: for input string: ""
```

I don't know the size of an input preliminarily.

Comment: You sure have tried something. Show it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After that I can't say more than Lutz Horn, it's the steps you have to do ;)

I made some small changes to your code and now it works for me ;)

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> vals = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Boolean>> truthtable = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Boolean>>();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String mark = "$";
    try {
        while (true) {
            String[] splitline = reader.readLine().split("\\s+");
            ArrayList<Integer> valsrow = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            ArrayList<Boolean> truthrow = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
            for (String element: splitline) 
            {
                if(!element.isEmpty())
                {
                    if (element.startsWith(mark))
                    {
                        truthrow.add(true);
                        element = element.substring(1, element.length());
                    }
                    else 
                        truthrow.add(false);

                    valsrow.add(Integer.parseInt(element.trim()));
                }
            }
            vals.add(valsrow); 
            truthtable.add(truthrow);
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("prob");
    }
```

enjoy ;)

Comment: but how do i read lines without even knowing, how much of them there will be? It will just raise an exception, when input will end.

Comment: You said : "From stdin i get a table like:

3 9 $12  $7  $2
4 $5  1 $4  $21
12  $11 0 0  $17 "
When you have this you know the length so you don't need a while true :)

Comment: I get it line by line, that's the problem

Comment: So everytime you get a new line you want to do something ?
first you get : `3 9 $12  $7  $2` then you will get the second etc but there is no end to your program ? what's the point ?

Comment: When there won't be any available input, IOException will be raised, caaught and a result will be returned.

Comment: I edit my post now it should be working ;) your replaceAll wasn't working mainly

Comment: For table parts like "3 #5 6", but for lines, starting with space (like " 3 #5 6" it throws a NumberFormatException. It looks like it does not strip first space and then tries to convert it to an integer, which produces an error.

Comment: I edited my answer now it will also work if there are space ;)

Answer (score 0):

That is easy.

1. Read each line.
2. Split it on whitespace.
3. Extract the number from each field, save it in a `int[][]` you have prepared.
4. Check if the `$` is in the field, note it in a `boolean[][]` you have prepared
5. Print both arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I think your first question is how to know when to stop reading. The answer is in the documentation for `Reader.readLine()`:

> Returns: A String containing the contents of the line, not including
>   any line-termination characters, **or null if the end of the stream has
>   been reached**

So the outer loop of your program is:

```
String line = reader.readLine();
while(line != null) {
    handleLine(line, numTable, boolTable);
    line = reader.readLine();
}
```

To make sure that works, write the simplest `handeLine()` that proves it works:

```
 public void handleLine(String line, 
                List<List<Integer>> numTable, List<List<Boolean>> boolTable) {
      System.out.println(line);
 }
```

Now that works, you can improve `handleLine()` to do the things you need.

Do them one at a time, and write them as small methods. Write small programs to exercise *just* the small method you are working on, before putting it all together. Or better still, find out about *jUnit*, which makes writing and keeping those small programs easier.